# how edit .htaccess to refirect subdomain to port 8080

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, subdomain

On my website `site.com` I have a subdomain `subdomain.site.com`
I have a service on port `subdomain.site.com:8080`
How can I redirect all users from `subdomain.site.com` to `subdomain.site.com:8080`

I would like to do it editing my .htaccess

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code should work:

```
# If we are on the subdomain
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^subdomain.site.com$

# If the port isn't 8080
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^8080$

# We redirect to the same adresse with the port
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}:8080/$1 [R=301,L]
```